Automate SSH Reboot Command
i got two grandstream ip phones that once in a while losing the pbx registration, only solution i came by is rebooting them (surprise surprise)
my idea for the simplest way to do it is by using ssh reboot command
i can manually log in with putty and run the reboot command
so here's the thing
currently the script i wrote looks like this
Start-Process .\plink.exe -ArgumentList "admin@192.168.xxx.xxx -pw xxxxx" "reboot"
after running the script it prompts plink window with the text "Using username "admin".
Access granted. Press Return to begin session." and i have to press enter button (return) before i can procced with manually writing the reboot command
any idea how to automate this thing?
would love to hear if you have any better ideas for automating phone rebooting

if anyone in need of this, this is what we came up with (it's working)
$plinkPath = ".\plink.exe"
$hostt = "admin@192.168.xxx.xxx"
$password = "xxxx"
$command = "reboot`n"
$sendenter = "\n"

# Start plink process
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $plinkPath -ArgumentList "-pw", $password, $hostt -NoNewWindow -PassThru

# Wait for the connection to establish
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("reboot")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")


Why?? Just use the -no-antispoof.

in that case, how would you write the script?

Like in your question, just add the -no-antispoof to plink: Start-Process .\plink.exe -ArgumentList "admin@192.168.xxx.xxx -no-antispoof -pw xxxxx" "reboot"
